# Need to regularly unplug and plug in the headset for Skype to recognize it

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype

I have the problem that regularly when I get a Skype call, it starts using the laptop speakers instead of the headset. I need to unplug the headset, then plug it back in for Skype to recognize it. This happens so regularly I have to do it on almost every call.

Is there any solution to this issue? In the skype preferences, it is set up correctly to use the headset, also windows itself is configured to use the headset.

Comment: is it just skype you need to do this with ? or do other programs recognise it at all times ?

Comment: @PeterH Not sure about Microsoft Teams, other programs I don't know for sure - this is for work and I rarely need sound at all, mostly for skype/Teams calls.

Comment: can you test it and find out ? it makes solving a lot easier if you can define the problem as being with skype or the driver

Comment: I also have speakers built-in in the display, I think maybe after going to power-save mode it is reregistering and taking over as the "new speaker".